# How can my team and I work on the same server and the same database in ASP.NET?

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I feel like this question is so stupid and has a simple answer but I honestly can't find anything. 
So basically, so far, when making projects in ASP.NET, the way I used to connect with a database is by:

-opening SQLServer

-making a database  (for example: a database called School)

-opening my ASP.NET project

-going to appsettings.json file and adding something like this

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": 
"Server=LENOVOPC\\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=School;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=Test; 
 Password=Test"
  }
```

-and then going to my Startup.cs file adding this line

```
      services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(builder =>
        {
            builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
```

as you can see, I've been doing everything on my local server

so my question now is, how can my team and I work on the same server and the same database? Like how can I edit the above so that my friend can make changes to the same database that i'm working on?

Comment: Do you have the option of running SQL Server on a server that you can all access?

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll want your team working on your local sql database, so you probably want to have a SQL server somewhere (cloud, network, etc.) that you can both reach.  Then you'll replace your connection string with the string for that server.  You can google setting up a SQL server and that may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could commit the project to git, and each team member can pull each request to work and update the database.